# array of system objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to create an array of system objects in Matlab and then mex into C code?

For example, in C++ you can create vector where myClass is a user defined class. Is it possible to create the equivalent thing in Matlab using system objects and then build to C code?

Comment: Apparently yes, but you need a MATLAB compiler license: http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/gs/what-are-system-objects.html (btw, this I found by searching on Google for "System+Objects+MATLAB")

Comment: I know I can build system objects because I have been working with them for a while. But I do not see how to instantiate arrays of a system object. If it is possible to instantiate one, I am looking to see how and if it is possible to build that data type

Answer (score 1):

Creating ordinary arrays of System objects is not supported. You can place them in cell arrays. But code generation to C code or mex file does not support any array of classes. If you can give more detail on what you are trying to do with array of objects we can try to see whether there are alternate approaches to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was my observation too. I have a system object myObj such as vector<myObj> 10(exampleObj). Then I want to access and update each object depnding on when some condition is met. Is there any way to work around not having this ability in Matlab

Comment: If the number of objects are limited to about 10-20 you can pre-declare a struct with field names obj1, obj2 etc and then use dynamic field names like structname.([objname num2str(idx)]) to access individual objects. Here idx could be a loop index.